# Prevent login using OpenId Connect in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect

I've got an OpenIdConnect service running (Thinktecture IdSvr) and I can login to my app perfectly.

When a user successfully logs in using OpenId Connect I want to check if they exist in my client user store and either allow them to continue or log them out.

To do that I'm handling the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.Notifications` but I can't work out how to prevent the user from successfully logging on.

I assumed that not setting the `n.AuthenticationTicket` would prevent a principle from being created.

```
var userInfoClient = GetUserInfoClient();

var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
var email = GetEmailAddr(userInfo);

var user = GetClientUser(email)

if (user != null)
{
    // access and refresh token
    var tokenClient = GetTokenClient();

    var tokenResponse = await GetToken(tokenClient);

    claims.Add(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse .AccessToken));
    claims.Add(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse .ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
    claims.Add(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse .RefreshToken));
    claims.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
        new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims.Distinct(new ClaimComparer()),
            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType),
            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simple. All I did was throw a new `SecurityException` in the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event.